# Nmap and grepping of its results

Tags: grep, nmap

folks.i would like to do reverse dns resolution using nmap where the output will be like below

Ip address     resolved name

how do i go about it using grep, thanks

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the output, but here are two things anyway:

Comment: 1) I don't think this is a programming question 2)NMAP can do reverse  DNS by giving it the -R flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
nmap 8.8.8.8 | awk '/report/ {split($NF,a,"[()]");print a[2],$5}'
8.8.8.8 google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

Comment: This does a full port scan just to output the DNS name. Better to use the -sL option to skip port scanning and host discovery.

Answer (score 0):

The option to do reverse name resolution in Nmap (without also doing a port scan or host discovery) is `-sL`. Nmap also has a machine-readable output format called [Grepable](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) output, using the `-oG` option.

Your question asks for a solution using grep, but extracting portions of output lines is not grep's strong suit. For this, you can use awk instead:

```
nmap -sL 192.0.2.0/24 -oG - | awk '/^Host/{print $2, $3}'
```

This will have the output in this format:

```
64.13.134.52 (scanme.nmap.org)
```

If you want to remove the parentheses, you can pipe the output through `tr`:

```
nmap -sL 192.0.2.0/24 -oG - | awk '/^Host/{print $2, $3}' | tr -d '()'
```